# linked list node bug infinity loop of node and insert between node

Tags: c, linked-list

when i created the third node it made the infinity loop of that node. what should i do? 
and please insert the code in case 'b' for insert node behind some node.

part1-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h> 
#include<stdbool.h>

char p,j ;
int v;

struct node{
int val;
struct node *next;
};

struct node *head=NULL;
struct node *curr=NULL;
struct node *temp=NULL;
struct node *prev=NULL;
struct node *tail=NULL;
struct node *after=NULL;
```

part2-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

```
struct node *creatFirstNode(int val){

   printf("\ncreating list with headnode as [%d]\n",val);
   struct node *ptr=(struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
   if(ptr==NULL){
                  printf("\nCreated Failed \n");
                  return NULL;       
   }
   ptr->val=val;
   ptr->next=NULL;

   head=ptr;
   curr=ptr;

  return ptr;
}
```

part3-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

```
main(){
   int  n,i;
   struct node *A=(struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
   struct node *B=(struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
   struct node *C=(struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
   struct node *new=(struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
   struct node *addEnd=(struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
   struct node *addAmong=(struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node));


   printf("\n-------- Welcome to Linked List Program -----------\n\n");

   do{

   printf("\nAdd to 'h'ead or 't'ail or 'b'ehind value:");   
   scanf("%c",&p); 
   fflush(stdin);
```

part4-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

```
   switch(p)
{
    case 'h':
        printf("Enter value node:");
        scanf("%d",&v);
        fflush(stdin);
        if(head == NULL)
        {
                creatFirstNode(v);
                fflush(stdin);
        }
        else
        {
            curr=head;
            new->val=v;
            new->next=NULL;
            curr=new;
            curr->next=head;
            curr=curr->next;
            ("\ncreating list with headnode as [%d]\n",v);
            head=new;
            fflush(stdin);
        }
        //void printList();

   curr=head;
   printf("\n----Value in Liked list----\n");

   while(curr!=NULL){
              printf("[%d], ",curr->val); 
              curr=curr->next;  //change current node        
                    }
        break;
```

part5-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

```
    case 't':
        printf("Enter value node tail:");
        scanf("%d",&v);



        curr=head;
        while(curr!=NULL){ //Seek for last node
                tail=curr;
                curr=curr->next; // shift to next node

            }

       addEnd->val=v;
       addEnd->next=NULL;
       tail->next=addEnd;        
        tail=new;
       fflush(stdin); 

        //void printList();.
        curr=head;
   printf("\n----Value in Liked list----\n");

   while(curr!=NULL){


              printf("[%d], ",curr->val); 
              curr=curr->next;  //change current node

          }

        break;
```

part6-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

```
    case 'b':
        printf("Enter value node behind:");
        scanf("%d",&v);
        fflush(stdin);

        printf("Adding value [%d] in new node:",&v);
        printf("Add new node behind the value:");


        void printList();
        break;



        default:

        printf("\n     Invalid Input     ");
        getch();


}

}while(p != 'h' || p != 't' || p != 'b' );

getch();  
return 0;
 }
```

Comment: I think you should also declare struct node *next=NULL; struct node *before=NULL;:) Without these declarations the code looks incomplete.:)

Comment: Where are there nodes A, B, and C used?:)

Comment: 1) allocate each node.

Comment: Don't use [new](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/keyword) as a variable name, even if you're using a c compiler, that's not a good practice

Comment: BTW `p != 'h' || p != 't' || p != 'b'` always true.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow  1. then what should i do after define node *before?

2.It not be used. this code was adapted so A B C is from its old mission

Comment: @BLUEPIXY 1. give me an example for allocating for each node pls.

2.but why i still can do case 'h' and 't' and default?

Comment: @BPL i'll edit it thx 
then can you fix my probelm?

Comment: @ToonBoonyasit Sure, i could help, but, could you please first edit your question so the code becomes a [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? That is, a single block of code i can paste directly on my editor and compile/run directly (those parts text thingies are not helpful ones). Also, please add the input/steps you're using and also clarify the expected output. That way more people will be able to help you

Comment: @BPL thank you very much. Could you please tell me your contacts such as e-mail facebook or LineID then I will send the completed file to you

Comment: @ToonBoonyasit Hehe, sorry, but no thanks, I don't post personal data here. What I meant before was you should edit the **current thread**, so everybody will be able to help you out faster and you'll get more answers.

Comment: @BPL OK but i don't knnow where is the error in my code when i ran it and made the third node it was an unexpected loop

Comment: @ToonBoonyasit You should define these global variables. You should define them in code blocks where they are used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

example

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct node {
    int val;
    struct node *next;
} Node;

Node *head, *tail;

Node *new_node(int val){
    struct node *ptr = malloc(sizeof(*ptr));
    if(ptr==NULL){
        perror("malloc:");
        printf("\nFailed to create a new node.\n");
        return NULL;
    }
    ptr->val  = val;
    ptr->next = NULL;

    return ptr;
}

Node *creatFirstNode(int val){
    return head = tail = new_node(val);
}

void printList(void){
    Node *np = head;

    printf("\n----Value in Liked list----\n");
    while(np){
        printf("[%d], ", np->val);
        np = np->next;
    }
    printf("NULL\n");
}

void freeList(void){
    while(head){
        Node *np = head->next;
        free(head);
        head = np;
    }
    tail = NULL;
}

int main(void){
    char cmd =' ';

    printf("\n-------- Welcome to Linked List Program -----------\n\n");

    do {
        int v = 0;

        printf("\nAdd to 'h'ead or 't'ail or 'b'ehind value or 'p'rint or 'q'uit:");   
        scanf(" %c", &cmd);

        switch(cmd){
        case 'h':
            printf("Enter value node head:");
            scanf("%d", &v);
            if(head == NULL){
                creatFirstNode(v);
            } else {
                Node *np = new_node(v);
                np->next = head;
                head = np;
            }
            break;

        case 't':
            printf("Enter value node tail:");
            scanf("%d", &v);
            if(head == NULL){
                creatFirstNode(v);
            } else {
                tail = tail->next = new_node(v);
            }
            break;

        case 'b':
            printf("Enter value node behind:");
            scanf("%d", &v);
            printf("\nUnimplemented yet.\n");
            break;

        case 'p':
            printList();
            break;
        case 'q':
            freeList();
            printf("\nBye!\n");
            break;

        default:
            printf("\n     Invalid Input     ");
        }
    }while(cmd != 'q' );

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: thanks for your code. No more an unexpected loop!

1 issue left : i want case 'b' to add node and insert behind any node i want to

thx

Comment: `case 'b':` Do it yourself.

Comment: Ummm... Okay Thx very much Bro!! :))

Comment: some error to go please while(np->val != s) { prev=np; np =np->next; } prev->next=new_node; new_node->next=np->next; }

Comment: @ToonBoonyasit I think it is clearly wrong. I think you should ask new questions with [mcve].